# Laravel authorization middleware with Ajax call returns 403

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

When accessing my route from an Ajax request, I always get a 403 error. It doesn't even enter the Policy function.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:owns,mymodel'], function () {
        Route::get('myroute/{mymodel}/get', 'MyController@get')
            ->name('mymodel.get');
    });
});
```

If rather than attaching the middleware in my web.php (route) like the above file, I do it from my Controller function as follow:

```php
public function get(MyModel $model)
{
    $this->authorizeForUser(auth()->user(), 'owns', $model);
    // ...
}
```

Then the Authorization is working as expected. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in how Gate vs. Middleware works, but the same Route works fine if not requested in Ajax.

Comment: your parameter in your method signature should be the same name as your route parameter ..... `MyModel $mymodel`, assuming you want to be using route model binding here

Comment: @lagbox You are right! Thanks, it works.